# Is there any way to replace a for loop with something more efficient in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pygame

My code below checks surrounding pixels to my object's pixel in python.

```
self.surr = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

for i in range(9):
#for x in range(-1, 2):
    #for y in range(-1, 2):
        if i != 5:
            x = i % 3 - 2
            y = int((i % 3) / 3) - 1

        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            pass
        else:
            PAI = allPixels[(self.x + x) % width][(self.y + y) % height] if allPixels[(self.x + x) % width][(self.y + y) % height] != None else None

        self.surr[(y * 3) + x] = (PAI)

return self.surr
```

This returns a list of length 8 that holds either a `Pixel` object or `None`. allPixels is a 2D array that also holds wither a `Pixel` object or `None`.
I've tried then nested loops that are commented out but they run just a bit slower that the method I'm currently using. This however, is still too slow as if there are 3000 pixels on the screen, which is the lower bounds of the total pixels there will be on the screen in the end, do the maths and you have a LOT going on every frame.

How can I make this run faster using maybe NumPy or some other method?

If you want to see the whole code, it can be found here: https://pastebin.com/EuutUVjS

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: have a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: As a side note: 3000 pixels may sound like a lot to you, but it's really nothing to a computer. Even if it takes multiple microseconds for each loop iteration instead of nanoseconds, it's still fast enough to do at 60fps without using most of your frame time.

Comment: @abarnert I know but it seriously slows my program down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing inherently requires looping—but if you can move that looping into numpy, it'll often get 5-20x faster.

In your case, what you're trying to do is to compare each pixel to its neighbors. How can you do that as an array-wide operation? Simple: compare the array to the same array shifted by 1.

Here's a simpler example:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,4,8,16])
>>> for i in range(1, len(a)):
...     print(a[i] - a[i-1], end=' ')
1 2 4 8
>>> print(a[1:] - a[:-1])
[1 2 4 8]
```

---

So, for a 2D array, it's just:

```
north = a[:-1]
ne = a[:-1,1:]
east = a[:,1:]
se = a[1:,1:]
south = a[1:]
sw = a[1:,:-1]
west = a[:,:-1]
nw = a[:-1,:-1]
```

Note that this isn't wasting a whole lot of time or memory building 8 extra arrays; it's just creating 8 views over the same memory.

See [this answer on compsci](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/160854/27320) for an example of using these shifted arrays for a Conway Game of Life simulation.

If you want to handle the borders differently, you may need to "zero-extend" the array, but that's the only complexity you're likely to run into.

---

However, there's a limit to how much benefit you can get out of numpy if you're storing Python objects in it. Normally, you want to store arrays of numbers.

I don't know what's in your `Pixel` objects, but let's pretend they're just color values, as three floats. In that case, you can use a 2D array with a structured dtype of three floats, or just a 3D array (row by column by r-g-b), either way using NaN values in place of `None`.

If you do that, array-wide operations can operate at near-machine-native speeds, including using SIMD operations for data-parallelism. If you don't, only the looping happens at native speeds; the arithmetic within the loop is still just as slow as in non-Numpy Python.

Comment: Okay, thanks but how would i do something like this for a 2D array?

Comment: @ThomasAyling Updated the answer.

Comment: In the example that you gave, is the array that stores all the pixels noe dimentional?

Comment: @ThomasAyling The first example shows how to get the pixels to the left of each pixel in a 1D array. The second example shows how to get the pixels in each of the 8 directions from each pixel in a 2D array, and the Game of Life link is similarly using a 2D array.

Comment: i tried implementing this emthod but i get this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: @ThomasAyling Then you don't actually have a 2D array; you have a list of lists, or a list of 1D arrays, or something else. So first, you need to switch to using a 2D array.

Comment: I initialized my 2D array like this:  
`for x in range(width):
        allPixels.append([])
        for y in range(height):
            allPixels[x].append(None)`
is that not a 2D array?

Comment: @ThomasAyling That's not an array, that's a list. To make an array, you can use `allPixels = np.array(allPixels)`, or, better, just allocate the array in numpy in a single step in the first place. You may need to take a step back and work through a numpy tutorial to learn the difference.